# Como mapear uma imagem usando Areas e Coordenadas do Google.Cloud.Vision.Api

Tags: html, html5, imagem, canvas, xhtml

Ola, amigos!

Estou tentando mapear uma imagem, usando a tag do html5 "Area" que trabalha com poligonos, eu quero mapear um retangulo ou varios retangulos em cima de uma imagem "img".

Minha duvida é, eu tenho um Mapeamento que rebecebo ou tabem coordenadas desta forma:

```
[X:166 - Y:64] [X:245 - Y:64] [X:245 - Y:81] [X:166 - Y:81]
```

São coordenadas de uma área de uma imagem. o que quero e pegar essas coordenadas e mapeá-las usando a tag Area do HTML5 mas essa tag so aceita 4 tipos de coordenadas, como proceder ?

```html
<map name = “shape”> <area shape = “rect” alt=”parte 1” coords = “0, 0, 100, 100” href=”parte1.html”/> <area shape = “circle” alt=”parte 2” coords = “100, 100, 25” href=”parte2.html”/> <area shape = “poly” alt=”parte 3” coords = “116, 207, 186, 299, 49, 296” href=”parte3.html”/></map><img src=”imagem.jpg” usemap=”#shape” />
```

Pelo que vi "Area" só aceita 4 coordenadas e agora.

Comment: Tem como vc explicar melhor qual tipo de forma q essas coordenadas precisam criar?? Pq a ordem delas está um pouco confuso para mim, já que todos os pontos se repetem duas vezes cada em ordem diferente.

Comment: Entao, a API da Google.Cloud.Vision me retorna essa informacao 
[X:166 - Y:64] [X:245 - Y:64] [X:245 - Y:81] [X:166 - Y:81] ou seja essa informacao e a Horizontal de Vertical de cada Coordenada perceba que sao 4 coordenadas cada um com horizontal e vertial formando um retangulo ou quadrado (poligono). ok.

Minha duvida e como eu uso a tag Area do HTML5 sendo esta para atributo Shape dela aceita domente 4 coordenadas eu nao entendi direito a essa parte demarcacao que a tag Area usa entende!?

Answer (score 0):

Tem q ver se essas coordenadas são para duas áreas do tipo rect para formar dois quadrados, ou se são para uma unica área num polígono.

Pq se for um polígono pelas coordenadas que está ai, não vai aparecer dois quadrados, vai aparecer outro shape com pontos misturados.

Numa área estilo rect vc pode por somente 4 coordenadas, sendo **x1, y1** que é o ponto de partida e **x2, y2** que é o ponto final.

Se for nesse esquema suas coordenadas deveria ter duas áreas rect mais ou menos assim?

```
<area shape = “rect” alt=”parte 1” coords = “x1, y1, x2, y2” href=”parte1.html”/>
<area shape = “rect” alt=”parte 1” coords = “x3, y3, x4, y4” href=”parte1.html”/>
```

Num polígono vc pode por quantas coordenadas em pares desejar, e cada uma será equivalente a um ponto no estilo **x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 e etc...**.

E então seguindo o seu código seria algo assim:

```
<area shape = “poly” alt=”parte 3” coords = “x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4” href=”parte3.html”/>
```

E dessa forma vc poderia colocar todas suas 4 coordenadas numa mesma área.

Agora só fique atento pela ordem, pq a imagem vem primeiro e o mapa depois.

No seu código vc está colocando a tag da imagem depois da tag do mapa, e é o contrário.

Qualquer coisa nesse link vc pode encontrar mais informações:

https://www.html-5-tutorial.com/map-and-area-elements.htm